# Custom PHP Extension Cross Compatibility

Tags: php, php-extension

I am building my first PHP Extension using https://www.zend.com/resources/writing-php-extensions as a roadmap and running into some interesting (to me) issues.

Installed on the server is PHP 7.2, but the current `master` version is 7.4. I copied the `php-src-master` onto the server and do the first step of `php ext_skel.php --ext test --dir`  and then

```
# phpize
# ./configure
# make
```

I then get this error:

```
/bin/bash /root/php-src-master/ext/test/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/root/php-src-master/ext/test -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/php-src-master/ext/test/include -I/root/php-src-master/ext/test/main -I/root/php-src-master/ext/test -I/usr/include/php/20170718 -I/usr/include/php/20170718/main -I/usr/include/php/20170718/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20170718/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20170718/ext -I/usr/include/php/20170718/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/php-src-master/ext/test/test.c -o test.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/root/php-src-master/ext/test -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/php-src-master/ext/test/include -I/root/php-src-master/ext/test/main -I/root/php-src-master/ext/test -I/usr/include/php/20170718 -I/usr/include/php/20170718/main -I/usr/include/php/20170718/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20170718/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20170718/ext -I/usr/include/php/20170718/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/php-src-master/ext/test/test.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/test.o
In file included from /root/php-src-master/ext/test/test.c:10:0:

/root/php-src-master/ext/test/test_arginfo.h:8:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ZEND_ARG_TYPE_INFO_WITH_DEFAULT_VALUE [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
ZEND_ARG_TYPE_INFO_WITH_DEFAULT_VALUE(0, str, IS_STRING, 0, "\"\"")
```

If I download the src for 7.2, then everything works just fine. I guess I am surprised because I haven't edited any code at all at this point, so I would think this is the equivalent of a `Hello World` system, which seems like it would have ultimate compatibility between versions and so wouldn't throw an error unless I was calling functions that didn't exist in the installed version. If that is true and a "new" function is being called that wasn't in 7.2, it seems weird that a basic skeleton would be utilizing functions that didn't exist in 7.2 to display "Hello World".

If I were to create and compile in 7.2, would I later be able to compile in 7.4? If I compile in 7.4, will I be able to use it in 7.2?

The extensions I want to build will have very simple jobs, but ones that need to be done rapidly and frequently. Things like formatting phone numbers, filtering json, processing recursive tree relationships, and so on.

Having seen this compatibility issue, I am curious if this is going to lock me into using a specific version of PHP where even when I am not trying to use any new functions in my code, I still have to rewrite it every time we upgrade PHP in the coming years.

Comment: implicit-function-declaration means that it couldn't find the function at link time.  You probably need `-l` and maybe `-L` to tell the linker where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The skeletons for a specific PHP version branch may use functionality/internal APIs introduced in said version, if you want to build an extension compatible with a lower PHP version you should work from the PHP extension skeleton of said PHP version, not on from a more recent one.